# VS Code stopped showing (some) images in Markdown preview

Tags: markdown, visual-studio-code

I currently keep all of my notes as Markdown files. Those files contain mainly links, and for some extra flair, I include the favicon of the site in front of them like this:

```
# Git

## Tutorials

- ![][fav-atlassian.com] [Git Tutorials and Training | Atlassian Git Tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials)
- ![][fav-codecademy.com] [Git Tutorial: Learn Git Basics For Free | Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-git)

[fav-atlassian.com]: https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.atlassian.com
[fav-codecademy.com]: https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.codecademy.com
```

I use Google's S2 service to get the favicon and `![][fav-atlassian.com]` renders it. The result is the following:

---

## Git

### Tutorials

- [image] [Git Tutorials and Training | Atlassian Git Tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials)
- [image] [Git Tutorial: Learn Git Basics For Free | Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-git)

---

As you can see, this Markdown renders as expected here, but not in VS Code anymore (it used to, until recently). VS Code seems to render a single space in the place of those favicons. What I've already tried:

- Checked if the same markdown renders fine in other tools, both windows and online
- Changed `Preview Security Settings` to `Disable - Allow all content and script execution` from `Strict - only load secure content` (in VS Code)
- Checked if *normal* images render correctly
- I add some `CSS` (and gave specific dimensions to all `img`) to check if those images *are* rendered but with the wrong the dimensions (possibly `0x0` or `1x1`)
- I checked the terminal/output for any errors

None of the above produced any results. I don't know what else to try in order to find a solution. Any thought?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It resolved itself after updating to 1.29.0